# What is the MicroMeter equivalent to a Prometheus simpleclient Collector?

Tags: micrometer

With Prometheus if I have several metrics that need to be collected at once, I would create a collector like so:

```
    public List<MetricFamilySamples> collect() {
        List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = getNetworkInterfaces();
        if(networkInterfaces.isEmpty()){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        NetworkMetricFamilies networkMetrics = new NetworkMetricFamilies();
        collect(networkMetrics, networkInterfaces);

        return networkMetrics.asList();
    }
```

I would implement a `collect()` method that would return a list of the needed metrics.

What is the equivalent with MicroMeter?

Answer (score 0):

All metrics are collected on each scrape. There is no efficiency to be gained by packing distinct metric names or combinations of tags into a single set of measurements.

Rather, iterate over the network interfaces and register any number of metrics for each.